# clamp a 2D coordinate to fit within an ellipse

Tags: opengl, 2d, mathematics, coordinates

I need to clamp a 2D coordinate to fit within an ellipse.

Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2 does something similar where capture points are translated from a 3D vector in the world to a 2D screen coordinate and then the 2D coordinates are clamped within an ellipse.

When the capture points are in view they're within the bounds of the ellipse.

[image: coordinates that are on screen]

When they're behind you they are clamped to be within the bounds of the ellipse.
[image: coordinates that are off screen]

Given a 2D coordinate that could be off screen, etc, what is the math behind clamping it within an ellipse?

Comment: The ellipse is 2D too, right? If not, what plane is it in?

Comment: Yes, the ellipse is 2D.

Comment: Can you scale the points and the ellipse to make the ellipse into a circle, clamp to the circle (relatively easy), then scale the points back?

Comment: @amitp: Why? Just use the well known equation for an ellipse at the origin and just use a simple convolution by the transformation that takes it to the origin.

Comment: simple: change coordinates so the ellipse is at 0,0 and round; limit vector length; change coordinates back.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a general method to clamp a point \$A\$ to the ellipse of center \$C\$ and half-dimensions \$d\$ (i.e. the ellipse is \$2d_x\$ wide and \$2d_y\$ high):

- \$B =  \frac{(A - C)}{d}\$ gives you the coordinates of \$A\$ in the frame in which the ellipse is the unit circle. The fraction is memberwise division (\$ \frac{a}{b} = (\frac{a_x}{b_x} ; \frac{a_y}{b_y})\$)
- \$B' = \frac{B}{|B|}\$ normalizes \$B\$: \$B'\$ is now on the unit circle.
- \$B'' = C + B' × d\$, where **\$×\$** is the memberwise product. This brings our clamped point back into the original frame : \$B''\$ is \$A\$, clamped onto the ellipse.

This method can be greatly simplified if the ellipse is centered (\$C\$ disappears), and/or if your frame has the same aspect ratio as your ellipse (\$d_x = d_y\$, so the scaling isn't necessary).

Answer (score 0):

[The equation for an ellipse](http://www.mathopenref.com/coordgeneralellipse.html) centered at the origin is just:

$$\bigg( \frac{x ^ 2}{Rx ^ 2}\bigg) + \bigg(\frac{y ^ 2}{Ry ^ 2} \bigg) = 1$$

where:

- Rx is the X-dimension radius; and
- Ry is the y-dimension radius

Combining this with a transformation that maps the relevant ellipse to the origin is straightforward.

Then just replace the *=* sign with a *<=* to get a test for (inclusive) containment in the ellipse.

Comment: right, I've gotten that far but all that lets us know is if the point is inclusive or exclusive in the ellipse, not where the closest point on the ellipse

Comment: extrude it: take the normal vector of the point to the center of the ellipse and then extrude it to the intersection point on the edge of the ellipse

Comment: @RockyBreslow: That's just going to be the intersection of the line segment from origin to point and the equation of the ellipse.